# Keep-presence stopped working

Tags: apt, mouse

i installed keep-presence and it works properly for few days but after that it stopped working. In terminal i see the process starts and it displayed process move mouse but nothing happens and PC going to sleep after a time period. Does anyone know solution? I try reinstall it, change settings for keep-presence but nothing help.

installation software was through command: `sudo snap install keep-presence`
version of Ubuntu is `x64 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`
in terminal i see:

```
 Idle detection
 Moved mouse to:  (16, 376)
 Shift key pressed
```

but after that nothing happened

Thank you

Comment: How did you install this software? What does it do? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412496/edit) the question to add more information.

Comment: descprition edited i hope it is ok now

Comment: I come back to my desk, my monitors are off and the log shows that keep moved the mouse and hit the shift key. I also installed with snap. keep-presence -m both -r 60 240 -p 10. Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: There's an issue with pynput and Wayland: https://github.com/carrot69/keep-presence/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to Ubuntu environment of the logged in account.
I resolved it by switching to **Xorg** environment.

Switch to **Xorg**:

1. Log out of ubuntu or restart the system.
2. Click the setting icon below the password section or bottom right corner.
3. Click on **Xorg** option and login.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

you can use simple alternative, I've wrote in bash
https://github.com/xpmn/wayland_mouse_jiggler

It's grab your input device and imitate random movement with evemu once in a second. It's a simple and have some limitations (it don't work with touchpad), but still doing the expected things

How to run: download the mouse.sh file
put it somewhere. Make it executable by `chmod +x ./mouse.sh` and after it run it with `sudo ./mouse.sh`. It will run in terminal and can be terminated by Ctrl+C

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your script does and how to use it? Right now, you answer contains no actionable information, but only a link to an external site, which doesn't qualify for a quality answer on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArturMeinild OP is suggesting an alternate piece of software which is hosted on Github.  While technically "link only answers" don't qualify, and OP *should* explain more what this script does, it still technically "qualifies" as an answer saying "Here's an alternative piece of software to do the same thing".  Unfortunately, this is one of those edge cases where it is both an answer and not an answer at the same time.

Comment: I'll happily remove my downvote if you include instructions on how to install the script, and how to run it. I know this is pretty basic information, but nonetheless should be included, so you can just copy-and-paste the commands from this answer. It's called convenience. 